# SQL Server : column data extraction

Tags: sql-server

One of my SQL Server column has tuples stored in it.

I just want to extract a `Room_ID` from `Module_ref` column along with its value from the column.

Example:

```
module_ref
{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111,222", "Test_ID":"9"}
{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111", "Test_ID":"9"}
{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "None", "Test_ID":"9"}
{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111,222,333", "Test_ID":"9"}
```

Expected output

```
Room_ID
------------
111,222
111
None
111,222,333
```

Comment: What is your question here? You've said what you want, but not asked us anything. What have you tried so far? What version of SQL Server? If 2016+ have you had a look at `OPENJSON`? If 2014 or prior I don't (personally) suggest using SQL Server for this as it does not support JSON natively.

Comment: What have you tried? What version of SQL-Server are you using? I

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `NON JSON` solution which uses `charindex()` & `substring()` :

```
select substring(data_col, 1, charindex('"', data_col)-1) as Room_ID
from table cross apply
     ( values (charindex('Room_ID', t.col) + 11) 
     ) tt(char_index) cross apply
     ( values (substring(t.col, tt.char_index, len(t.col))) 
     ) ttt(data_col);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *are* using SQL Server 2016+ then, as I mentioned, use `OPENJSON`:

```
SELECT OJ.RoomID
FROM (VALUES('{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111,222", "Test_ID":"9"}'),
            ('{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111", "Test_ID":"9"}'),
            ('{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "None", "Test_ID":"9"}'),
            ('{"ID": 1, "Room_ID": "111,222,333", "Test_ID":"9"}'))V(JSON)
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(V.JSON) 
                 WITH (ID int '$.ID',
                       RoomID varchar(500) '$.Room_ID',
                       TestID int '$.Test_ID') OJ;
```

*Ideally, afterwards, you should then use a string splitter to change your data to a normalised value.*